# onCreate in an extends baseActivity

Tags: android

BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected BottomNavigationViewEx navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentViewId());

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.bnve);
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        navigationView.enableAnimation(false);
        navigationView.enableShiftingMode(false);
        navigationView.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
        navigationView.setTextVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        updateNavigationBarState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item1) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item2) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, test2.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item3) {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, test3.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item4) {
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, test4.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.itemcen) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void updateNavigationBarState(){
        int actionId = getNavigationMenuItemId();
        selectBottomNavigationBarItem(actionId);
    }

    void selectBottomNavigationBarItem(int itemId) {
        MenuItem item = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(itemId);
        item.setChecked(true);
    }

    abstract int getContentViewId();

    abstract int getNavigationMenuItemId();
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    int getContentViewId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
        return R.id.item1;
       }

}
```

I have this BaseActivity and all the other activities are same as the MainActivity

My problem is that I don't know how to code inside each activity since when I add onCreate method inside the activity it doesn't work and the bottomNavigationBar gets missed up and stops working as expecting.

This is how I add the `onCreate`

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    int getContentViewId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    int getNavigationMenuItemId() {
        return R.id.item1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

Comment: show how you add oncreate

Comment: just create a abstract method in BaseActivity and call in onCreate, Override the same in MainActivity and do what is neccessary and remove onCreate in MainActivity

Comment: don't call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `MainActivity`. Because in your `uper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` it already sets content view, and operates your  `navigationView`. Then after you call `setContentView` in your `MainActivity`, it overwrites the view with new one.

Comment: Vladyslav Matviienko it worked when I deleted setContentView but once I added a button inside onCreate the app crashed

Comment: see the crash stacktrace to get the reason of the crash

Comment: ok it worked now thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

add this in your base activity

```
abstract void onCreateFinished();
```

call this in last line of onCreate();

then in your subclass you can do whatever.

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you please explain further I didn't quite get how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Use onPostCreate() don't  override on Create() as if your layout for every activity is same,Use the onCreate() once only in your base activity

Answer (score 0):

just add an abstract method in your Base class

```
    abstract void onViewReady(Bundle b);
    onCreate(Bundle saveIns){
    .....
    at the last line call the abstract method
    onViewReady(savins);
}
```

then in your

```
AnotherActivity extends BaseActivity{
  @overrride
  void onViewReady(Bundle b){
     //do stuff
   }
}
```